# Docker Errors For Ubuntu on Sudo Apt-get update

Tags: package-management, updates

A while back I installed Docker, but don't remember what I did.

I'm still learning/getting used to Linux and am unsure how to get rid of the following error.

When I run `sudo /apt-get update` I get the following error. How can get rid of this error?

I'd like just to eliminate this error, not reinstall Docker, do /I need to revert the `add-apt-repository` action that I did when installing?

```
Err:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:21d5:ae00:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]   
Err:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian eoan Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:21d5:ae00:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Hit:19 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Each error occurs when you add try to use source that does NOT support your current release of Ubuntu. Docker does not provide a repository to support Ubuntu 19.10. Disable that source.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks others for the context. In case this helps, to actually resolve the error, I resolved it by running:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then just removing the repo source for eoan and making sure I was using the following:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

After that I can run `apt-get` without issue.